# Can you determine the git version of a file copied from a repo?

Tags: git, github

I inherited an XCode project that uses code from the CocoaAsyncSocket project (available on GitHub). The files (AsyncSocket.m/h) were copied into the XCode project so I have no git history.

I need to find what version of the files I have. Is there a way I can compare my files (assuming they haven't been edited) with the repo's history to see which commit I have?

Comment: git blame the file and go ask the dev the did it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First compute the hash of your file using `git hash-object`.
Then you can use `git ls-tree` to list the hashes of each commit in question.

I would use something like this:

```
file=AsyncSocket.m
hash=$(git hash-object $file)
for i in $(git rev-list  HEAD -- $file); do
   git ls-tree $i|grep -q $hash && echo $i
done|xargs -l git log -1 --oneline --decorate
```

Comment: That did it! Such awesomeness.

Answer (score 2):

Not a simple way that I know of, especially if a particular version of that file appears in more than one version of the overall project (i.e. that file didn't change between releases).

However, you could `git hash-object -t blob AsyncSocket.h` to get the hash for that file, then use `git ls-tree -r <some_version_tag>^{tree} | grep <hash>` repeatedly for the different version tags to figure out what version(s) included that file. Of course, if it's been modified in anyway since it was "imported", this won't work unless you can get your hands on a pristine copy...